# How can I search for the first instance of a term in each paragraph of a document in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to search for and highlight two words--say, "box" and "blue"--throughout a Word document. But I only want to highlight the first instance of each word in each paragraph. Sometimes in my document, the word "box" pops up 6 or 7 times in a paragraph, and that's too much. I just want to know the paragraph involves the word "box" with a single highlight.

I can search for all the instances of these two words with the code below. Unfortunately, however, my attempts at doing what I say above have been so disastrous that I am embarrassed to write more code than what works below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
Sub BoxBlue()
Dim range As range
Dim i as Long
Dim tlist

tlist = array("box", "blue")
For i = 0 to UBound(tlist)
Set range = ActiveDocument.range
With range.Find
.Text = tlist(i)
.Format = True
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False

Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
range.HighlightColorIndex=wdYellow

Loop
End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: use the Paragraphs collection of the Document object. Then use Range.Find

Comment: Hi Sorceri, we are thinking along the same lines. I will need to use the paragraphs option and loop the code each time--through each paragraph--until I get the first result in each paragraph down to the end of the document  Does that sound about right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, ArrFnd()
ArrFnd = Array("box", "blue")
For i = 0 To UBound(ArrFnd)
  With ActiveDocument.Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = ArrFnd(i)
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = True
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found = True
      .HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
      .End = .Paragraphs.Last.Range.End
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, macropod! This code ran fine but did not produce my desired result. It continues to highlight all instances of both words rather than the first instance in each paragraph. I will keep plugging away at it, though!

Comment: An update: macropod, I played with your answer and removed .Wrap = wdFindStop. And now it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: The code *as posted* does exactly what you asked for. Removing .Wrap = wdFindStop is liable to result in Word running into an endless loop.

Comment: Hello macropod, a well-deserved apology! I ran the code again as you originally sent it, and it worked. I don't know what happened on Friday. Many thanks. I tried to upvote you last week, and it registered, but it does not show publicly because I have fewer than 15 points. Have a nice day.